# Unable to start activity from the different package [Android]

Tags: android

I have two different activities in two packages as following:

1. com.my.application.MyActivity1
2. com.my.application.Test.MyActivity2

In my manifest file i have
 `package="com.my.application"`
and bothe the activities are in the same `application` tag.

I am starting MyActivity1 from within .Test.MyActivity2 using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity1.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I get following logs in log cat while starting the application:

```
I/ActivityManager( 1305): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.my.application/.MyActivity1 } from pid 2336
D/dalvikvm( 1886): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 133K, 51% free 2687K/5447K, external 1527K/1559K, paused 56ms
D/dalvikvm( 1886): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 12K, 51% free 2675K/5447K, external 9796K/11844K, paused 40ms
D/AndroidRuntime( 1886): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 1886): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2018d560)
I/ActivityManager( 1305): Process com.my.application (pid 2336) has died.
```

After call to `startActivity` function my application segments/crashes and i am not able to see the MyActivity2 launched/started.

So is it not possible to start activity from within the different packages in android.

Thanks,
PP.

Comment: nope, it's possible. It's even possible to start Activities from 3rd party apps.

Comment: Can you provide your Manifest file? seems like there is some problems with path to `MyActivtiy1`

Comment: Sorry but i can't provide my manifest file sorry.

Comment: Also i am not getting any trace logs to debug, when i put start activity function in the try catch block, don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible :) and your launch is correct, so it must be setup that is something wrong with. To be exact you should start activity2 from activity1 why you ask well the manifest is the answer I say. You see the package refered to in the manifest is where your main activity should reside.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Manifest

it should be like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.application" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <application  android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:icon="@drawable/logo_android">
        <activity android:name=".MyActivity1" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Test.MyActivity2" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I this this will help you.

Comment: It is the same but Intent-filter MAIN and LAUNCHER defined in MyActivity1 is in tag of .Test.MyActivity2 as my Application starts with MyActivty2. Do i need to add intent-filter->action->MAIN to MyActivity1 also?

Comment: No.,you do not need to add intent-filter->action->MAIN  tags to sub activity. That tag intent-filter->action->MAIN represents only for the launcher activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,com.packagename.activityname);
```

also in manifest,

```
<activity android:name=".packagename.Activityname" />
```

instead of `<activity android:name=".Activityname" />`

Comment: yes i have also tried it and in my manifest files also i have package name with activity name as you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to do with one package to another. Use this code to do that

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("another package name","another package's main activity"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

It's work fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this:
put this in manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="applicationB.intent.action.Launch" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

then call like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("applicationB.intent.action.Launch");
startActivity(intent);
```